# jQuery not working on slide for every single div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a project and I'm trying to make a toggle jQuery slide-up and down for every container, but with the same id on action.

Unfortunately, it works only for the first container. I have like 9 similar containers left, but I need a function to call for every single div.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

```css
#panel, #flip {
    padding:10px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #38ada9;
    border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

#panel {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
 <html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Proiect -Website-</title>
    <!---Boostrap Ver 3.3.7 --->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Font Awesome Icon Library -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!---J-Query ---> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--- Animation Ajax --->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>
 <!---- NUMARUL 10 ----->
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h2 id="primul" style="color:darkmagenta;"> 10. Samsung S9+ </h2>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="telefoane/s9.jpg" alt="Samsung S9+">
       <!-- Thin Size Progress Bars -->
    <div class="margin">
    <h3 class="progress-label">Rapiditate
    <span class="pull-right">85%</span>
    </h3>
    <div class="progress progress-xxs" style="height:12px;">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="92" aria-valuemin="0" id="first" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 92%">
    </div>
    </div>
    <h3 class="progress-label">Rezistenta
    <span class="pull-right">68%</span>
    </h3>
    <div class="progress progress-xxs" style="height:12px;">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="68" aria-valuemin="0" id="second" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 68%;">
    </div>
    </div>
    <h3 class="progress-label">Performanta
    <span class="pull-right">81%</span>
    </h3>
    <div class="progress progress-xxs" style="height:12px;">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="78" aria-valuemin="0" id="third" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 78%">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
      <!-- End Thin Size Progress Bars -->
      <div class="caption">
        <h3 style="color:#c0392b;text-align:center;padding-bottom:16px;">Caracteristici: <i class="fa fa-mobile"></i></h3>  
        
        
        
        <!------ THIS IS THE JQUERY SLIDE ---------->
        <div id="flip">Apasa pentru detalii</div>       
        <div id="panel">
        
        
            <p class="text-bold">Display Super AMOLED</p><p>6.2 inch cu rezoluție 2960×1440 pixeli, aspect 18.5:9, 529 ppi, protejat cu sticlă Corning Gorilla Glass 5, 3D Touch pentru butonul de Home, certificare IP68 în ce privește contactul cu apa și praful, raport display / corp de 84.2%;</p>
            <p class="text-bold">Procesor Exynos 9810 Octa</p><p> 4 x Mongoose M3 la 2.8 GHz și 4 x ARM Cortex-A55 la 1.7 GHz și Mali-G72 MP18 sau Qualcomm Snapdragon 845 de tip octa-core cu 4 x Kryo 385 la 2.7 GHz și 4 x Kryo 385 Silver la 1.7 GHz, 6 GB RAM și 64 / 128 / 256 GB spațiu de stocare, slot pentru cardurile microSD de până la 400 GB;</p>
            <p class="text-bold">Android 8.0 Oreo</p>
            <p>4G cu viteze de până la 1200 Mbps în download și 200 Mbps în upload, Wi-Fi a/b/g/n/ac, dual-band, Wi-Fi direct, hotspot, bluetooth 5.0, USB type-C, NFC, jack de 3.5 mm, A-GPS, GLONASS, BDS și GALILEO;</p>
            <p class="text-bold">Camera</p>
            <p>12 Megapixeli cu f/1.5 sau 2.4, dimensiune a pixelului de 1.4 microni + 12 Megapixeli cu f.2.4, zoom optic 2x, Dual Pixel PDAF, detecție de fază pentru autofocus, OIS, LED flash, filmează la 2160p cu 30 fps, filmează la 720p cu 960 fps, cameră frontală de 8 Megapixeli cu f/1.6 ce filmează la 1440p;</p>
             <p class="text-bold">Baterie</p>
            <p>3500 mAh, 189 gr. și dimensiuni de 158.1 x 73.8 x 8.5 mm grosime.</p>
             <p class="text-bold" style="font-size:14px;">Pret: 600<i class="fa fa-eur"></i></p>
              <div align="right">
             <div class="button">
             <a href="https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s9+-8967.php" class="btn btn-one"> Mai multe </a></div>    
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>   
</div>
   
                                    <!---- NUMARUL 9 ----->

      <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h2 id="primul" style="color:darkmagenta;"> 10. Samsung S9+ </h2>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="telefoane/s9.jpg" alt="Samsung S9+">
       <!-- Thin Size Progress Bars -->
    <div class="margin">
    <h3 class="progress-label">Rapiditate
    <span class="pull-right">85%</span>
    </h3>
    <div class="progress progress-xxs" style="height:12px;">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="92" aria-valuemin="0" id="first" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 92%">
    </div>
    </div>
    <h3 class="progress-label">Rezistenta
    <span class="pull-right">68%</span>
    </h3>
    <div class="progress progress-xxs" style="height:12px;">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="68" aria-valuemin="0" id="second" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 68%;">
    </div>
    </div>
    <h3 class="progress-label">Performanta
    <span class="pull-right">81%</span>
    </h3>
    <div class="progress progress-xxs" style="height:12px;">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="78" aria-valuemin="0" id="third" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 78%">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
      <!-- End Thin Size Progress Bars -->
      <div class="caption">
        <h3 style="color:#c0392b;text-align:center;padding-bottom:16px;">Caracteristici: <i class="fa fa-mobile"></i></h3>  
        <div id="flip">Apasa pentru detalii</div>
        <div id="panel">
            <p class="text-bold">Display Super AMOLED</p><p>6.2 inch cu rezoluție 2960×1440 pixeli, aspect 18.5:9, 529 ppi, protejat cu sticlă Corning Gorilla Glass 5, 3D Touch pentru butonul de Home, certificare IP68 în ce privește contactul cu apa și praful, raport display / corp de 84.2%;</p>
            <p class="text-bold">Procesor Exynos 9810 Octa</p><p> 4 x Mongoose M3 la 2.8 GHz și 4 x ARM Cortex-A55 la 1.7 GHz și Mali-G72 MP18 sau Qualcomm Snapdragon 845 de tip octa-core cu 4 x Kryo 385 la 2.7 GHz și 4 x Kryo 385 Silver la 1.7 GHz, 6 GB RAM și 64 / 128 / 256 GB spațiu de stocare, slot pentru cardurile microSD de până la 400 GB;</p>
            <p class="text-bold">Android 8.0 Oreo</p>
            <p>4G cu viteze de până la 1200 Mbps în download și 200 Mbps în upload, Wi-Fi a/b/g/n/ac, dual-band, Wi-Fi direct, hotspot, bluetooth 5.0, USB type-C, NFC, jack de 3.5 mm, A-GPS, GLONASS, BDS și GALILEO;</p>
            <p class="text-bold">Camera</p>
            <p>12 Megapixeli cu f/1.5 sau 2.4, dimensiune a pixelului de 1.4 microni + 12 Megapixeli cu f.2.4, zoom optic 2x, Dual Pixel PDAF, detecție de fază pentru autofocus, OIS, LED flash, filmează la 2160p cu 30 fps, filmează la 720p cu 960 fps, cameră frontală de 8 Megapixeli cu f/1.6 ce filmează la 1440p;</p>
             <p class="text-bold">Baterie</p>
            <p>3500 mAh, 189 gr. și dimensiuni de 158.1 x 73.8 x 8.5 mm grosime.</p>
             <p class="text-bold" style="font-size:14px;">Pret: 600<i class="fa fa-eur"></i></p>
              <div align="right">
             <div class="button">
             <a href="https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s9+-8967.php" class="btn btn-one"> Mai multe </a></div>    
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use the same id for any more than one element ever. not ever. never ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever. That's what classes are for.

Comment: if i use class.. when i press the div , it just expands all at the same time , i dont want that

Comment: loop over each returned element one by one. For instance `$(".class").each` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: You should use the *same* `class` on every div to apply the styling, **and** a *different* `id` to trigger the expand

Comment: @aquaforce that issue (*it just expands all at the same time*) is usually related to doing a global selector, rather than a contextual one.  Sounds like that is your real question you should be asking us about.

Comment: There is _no_ reason to use the same id more than once. If you're thinking "but this one thing" _don't_, There is _no_ reason. None. No exception.

Comment: Can you help me with an example in my case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

code snippet added

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".flip").click(function() {
    var divs = $(this).next("div.panel");
    divs.slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
.panel,
.flip {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #38ada9;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.panel {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Font Awesome Icon Library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!---J-Query --->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--- Animation Ajax --->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>
<!---- NUMARUL 10 ----->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h2 id="primul" style="color:darkmagenta;"> 10. Samsung S9+ </h2>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="telefoane/s9.jpg" alt="Samsung S9+">
      <!-- Thin Size Progress Bars -->
      <div class="margin">
        <h3 class="progress-label">Rapiditate
          <span class="pull-right">85%</span>
        </h3>
        <div class="progress progress-xxs" style="height:12px;">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="92" aria-valuemin="0" id="first" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 92%">
          </div>
        </div>
        <h3 class="progress-label">Rezistenta
          <span class="pull-right">68%</span>
        </h3>
        <div class="progress progress-xxs" style="height:12px;">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="68" aria-valuemin="0" id="second" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 68%;">
          </div>
        </div>
        <h3 class="progress-label">Performanta
          <span class="pull-right">81%</span>
        </h3>
        <div class="progress progress-xxs" style="height:12px;">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="78" aria-valuemin="0" id="third" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 78%">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Thin Size Progress Bars -->
      <div class="caption">
        <h3 style="color:#c0392b;text-align:center;padding-bottom:16px;">Caracteristici: <i class="fa fa-mobile"></i></h3>



        <!------ THIS IS THE JQUERY SLIDE ---------->
        <div class="flip">Apasa pentru detalii</div>
        <div class="panel">


          <p class="text-bold">Display Super AMOLED</p>
          <p>6.2 inch cu rezoluție 2960×1440 pixeli, aspect 18.5:9, 529 ppi, protejat cu sticlă Corning Gorilla Glass 5, 3D Touch pentru butonul de Home, certificare IP68 în ce privește contactul cu apa și praful, raport display / corp de 84.2%;</p>
          <p class="text-bold">Procesor Exynos 9810 Octa</p>
          <p> 4 x Mongoose M3 la 2.8 GHz și 4 x ARM Cortex-A55 la 1.7 GHz și Mali-G72 MP18 sau Qualcomm Snapdragon 845 de tip octa-core cu 4 x Kryo 385 la 2.7 GHz și 4 x Kryo 385 Silver la 1.7 GHz, 6 GB RAM și 64 / 128 / 256 GB spațiu de stocare, slot pentru
            cardurile microSD de până la 400 GB;</p>
          <p class="text-bold">Android 8.0 Oreo</p>
          <p>4G cu viteze de până la 1200 Mbps în download și 200 Mbps în upload, Wi-Fi a/b/g/n/ac, dual-band, Wi-Fi direct, hotspot, bluetooth 5.0, USB type-C, NFC, jack de 3.5 mm, A-GPS, GLONASS, BDS și GALILEO;</p>
          <p class="text-bold">Camera</p>
          <p>12 Megapixeli cu f/1.5 sau 2.4, dimensiune a pixelului de 1.4 microni + 12 Megapixeli cu f.2.4, zoom optic 2x, Dual Pixel PDAF, detecție de fază pentru autofocus, OIS, LED flash, filmează la 2160p cu 30 fps, filmează la 720p cu 960 fps, cameră
            frontală de 8 Megapixeli cu f/1.6 ce filmează la 1440p;</p>
          <p class="text-bold">Baterie</p>
          <p>3500 mAh, 189 gr. și dimensiuni de 158.1 x 73.8 x 8.5 mm grosime.</p>
          <p class="text-bold" style="font-size:14px;">Pret: 600<i class="fa fa-eur"></i></p>
          <div align="right">
            <div class="button">
              <a href="https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s9+-8967.php" class="btn btn-one"> Mai multe </a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!---- NUMARUL 9 ----->

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h2 id="primul" style="color:darkmagenta;"> 10. Samsung S9+ </h2>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="telefoane/s9.jpg" alt="Samsung S9+">
      <!-- Thin Size Progress Bars -->
      <div class="margin">
        <h3 class="progress-label">Rapiditate
          <span class="pull-right">85%</span>
        </h3>
        <div class="progress progress-xxs" style="height:12px;">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="92" aria-valuemin="0" id="first" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 92%">
          </div>
        </div>
        <h3 class="progress-label">Rezistenta
          <span class="pull-right">68%</span>
        </h3>
        <div class="progress progress-xxs" style="height:12px;">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="68" aria-valuemin="0" id="second" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 68%;">
          </div>
        </div>
        <h3 class="progress-label">Performanta
          <span class="pull-right">81%</span>
        </h3>
        <div class="progress progress-xxs" style="height:12px;">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="78" aria-valuemin="0" id="third" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 78%">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Thin Size Progress Bars -->
      <div class="caption">
        <h3 style="color:#c0392b;text-align:center;padding-bottom:16px;">Caracteristici: <i class="fa fa-mobile"></i></h3>
        <div class="flip">Apasa pentru detalii</div>
        <div class="panel">
          <p class="text-bold">Display Super AMOLED</p>
          <p>6.2 inch cu rezoluție 2960×1440 pixeli, aspect 18.5:9, 529 ppi, protejat cu sticlă Corning Gorilla Glass 5, 3D Touch pentru butonul de Home, certificare IP68 în ce privește contactul cu apa și praful, raport display / corp de 84.2%;</p>
          <p class="text-bold">Procesor Exynos 9810 Octa</p>
          <p> 4 x Mongoose M3 la 2.8 GHz și 4 x ARM Cortex-A55 la 1.7 GHz și Mali-G72 MP18 sau Qualcomm Snapdragon 845 de tip octa-core cu 4 x Kryo 385 la 2.7 GHz și 4 x Kryo 385 Silver la 1.7 GHz, 6 GB RAM și 64 / 128 / 256 GB spațiu de stocare, slot pentru
            cardurile microSD de până la 400 GB;</p>
          <p class="text-bold">Android 8.0 Oreo</p>
          <p>4G cu viteze de până la 1200 Mbps în download și 200 Mbps în upload, Wi-Fi a/b/g/n/ac, dual-band, Wi-Fi direct, hotspot, bluetooth 5.0, USB type-C, NFC, jack de 3.5 mm, A-GPS, GLONASS, BDS și GALILEO;</p>
          <p class="text-bold">Camera</p>
          <p>12 Megapixeli cu f/1.5 sau 2.4, dimensiune a pixelului de 1.4 microni + 12 Megapixeli cu f.2.4, zoom optic 2x, Dual Pixel PDAF, detecție de fază pentru autofocus, OIS, LED flash, filmează la 2160p cu 30 fps, filmează la 720p cu 960 fps, cameră
            frontală de 8 Megapixeli cu f/1.6 ce filmează la 1440p;</p>
          <p class="text-bold">Baterie</p>
          <p>3500 mAh, 189 gr. și dimensiuni de 158.1 x 73.8 x 8.5 mm grosime.</p>
          <p class="text-bold" style="font-size:14px;">Pret: 600<i class="fa fa-eur"></i></p>
          <div align="right">
            <div class="button">
              <a href="https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s9+-8967.php" class="btn btn-one"> Mai multe </a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```